# Concurrent Map with one key and multiple values

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, thread-safety

I need to have a Map which is thread safe and can have multiple values. I did write one using `MultiMap` as

```
    private MultiMap<String, String> uploadIdETagMap = new MultiValueMap<String, String>();

//Function to get tag value and add to map to that uploadId key
    public void uploadPartForMultiPartUpload() {
        try {
            UploadPartRequest partRequest = new UploadPartRequest();
            partRequest = partRequest.withBucketName(bucketName).withInputStream(inputStream).withKey(fileName)
                    .withPartNumber(partNumber).withUploadId(uploadId).withPartSize(sizeOfData)
                    .withLastPart(isLastPart);
            UploadPartResult result = s3Client.uploadPart(partRequest);
            uploadIdETagMap.put(uploadId, result.getPartETag());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error uploading part: {} in multi part upload.", partNumber, e);
        }
    }

    List<String> tagList = (List<String>) uploadIdETagMap.get(uploadId);
```

So everytime i will get new tag value for a particular uplaodId key and i need all of those tags at the end and there will be other uploads processing same time.

In the above code, `tag` gets added every time as the value of the `MultiMap` for specific `uploadId` key.
The above code works, but both `MultiMap` and `MultiValueMap` is deprecated and not thread safe.

So any suggestion how can i achieve this with latest version and thread safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
personFavoriteColors.computeIfAbsent( 
    "Alice" , 
    ( x -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>() )
)
.add( "Purple" )
;

personFavoriteColors.computeIfAbsent( 
    "Alice" , 
    ( x -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>() )
)
.add( "Gold" )
;
```

> personFavoriteColors.toString(): [Purple, Gold]

## `Map::computeIfAbsent`

Java now has [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) behavior built-in with new [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method defined on the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) interface.

Define your map.

```
ConcurrentMap< String , Set< String> > personFavoriteColors = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>() ;
```

We are using a `Map` implementation that implements the [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) interface for thread-safety as you requested. Java offers two such implementations.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Use a single line to create a new list or set to hold the multiple values.

```
personFavoriteColors.computeIfAbsent( 
    "Alice" , 
    ( x -> new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>() )   // Lambda expression. Run only if needed to run (if absent). 
)                                          // Returns the value of a map (a `Set` or `List` when desiring a multimap). 
.add( "Purple" )
;
```

You may access the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) (or `List`) outside of the `Map` that owns it. So that `Set` (or `List`) must also be concurrent.

Here we used a concurrent set, [`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html) as our value for the map.

For example:

```
Set< String > favoriteColorsForAlice = personFavoriteColors.get( "Alice" ) ;
System.out.println( favoriteColorsForAlice ) ;
```

See this [code run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/xw0ZGH).

> [Purple, Gold]

Comment: I am confused, why do you use `computeIfAbsent` and not `putIfAbsent` in your example?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever `Map<String,List<String>>` implementation you use you could do the following:

```
String key;
String value;
map.compute(key, ((k,v)-> v == null ? new ArrayList<>() : v).add(value));
```

The above checks to see if the `List<String>` for key exists, if not it creates one, otherwise, it uses the existing one.  In both cases, the value is added to the new or existing list for a given key.

Comment: Actually, I will not have the list upfront, based on the key the value should be added with that existing key value. Suppose if i have two keys and value returned from that function would be a string, after adding the first value to a key, i should be able to add the next value to the same key or either. I will not be able to create a list of values and add, it should be one by one.

Comment: So for duplicate keys you are altering each one somehow to permit a one to one mapping of keys to values?  Can you show an example?

Comment: @ShivendraSharma  I'm sorry, I wasn't clear in what I meant.   What does the finished map look like.  You can just use strings.  Say you have a key "abcd".  So is it "abcd", then "abcd1" and "abcd2", whe 1,2,.. are the tags to change the keys for each value? Or do you  just append the next string to the existing value each time a value with the same key appears?

Comment: So, I have a key "abcd" and another key is "efgh", now values will come from a function as shown above based on key, now suppose after running that function once, i got "1234" as the value for key "abcd" and i saved that. Again got value as "4321" for key "abcd" and need to add that as value of "abcd" and so on. In between values will come for "efgh" as well so should be able to work same way for that.

Comment: But since maps cannot have duplicate keys, there are usually two choices.  One is to put them in a list, or if they are strings, they can be concatenated to the existing string, separated with a delimiter,  like a comma.  And per your earlier statement *I cannot have the list upfront*.  The list is created only when you need it ,as per my example.